# C# array accessiblity

Tags: c#, arrays

Is there a way to prevent reinitialization of an array? (to force specific length)

example initial:

```
int[] array = new int[3]{0,0,0};
```

usage:

```
array = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

The above usage will reinitialize the array with length of 5.

The array will always have 3 elements, but the values of the elements will always be changing.

I am trying to avoid doing the following to assign it's values:

```
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. What *exactly* are you trying to prevent? Which line should be invalid? What's wrong with `int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 }`?

Comment: You want to avoid 1 or 2? or both?

Comment: I want to prevent changing the length of the array via reinitialization such as my usage example. So, if try to use "array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }", it will just throw an exception or something.

Comment: Don't expose  the field. Make it as property. Validate the value in property setter.

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring it `readonly`:

```
readonly int[] array = new int[3]{0,0,0};
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether it is what you want, but I can propose to you the following wrapper class:

```
public class FixedArrayHolder<T>
{
    public FixedArrayHolder(Int32 fixedLength, T[] array)
    {
        if (fixedLength < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        if (array == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        this.FixedLength = fixedLength;
        this.Array = array;
    }

    public Int32 FixedLength
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private T[] m_array;

    public T[] Array
    {
        get
        {
            return this.m_array;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            if (value.Length != this.FixedLength)
                throw new ArgumentException();

            this.m_array = value;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator T[](FixedArrayHolder<T> fixedArray)
    {
        if (fixedArray == null)
            return null;

        return fixedArray.Array;
    }
}
```

You can use this class in place of standard arrays:

```
// Works
var array = new FixedArrayHolder<Int32>(3, new Int32[] { 1, 2, 3 });

// Works
array.Array = new Int32[] { 3, 4, 5 };

// Fails
array.Array = new Int32[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

**P.S.:** You can extend it with some indexer and IEnumerable, IList members to allow more streamlined access to elements if it is required.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int[] origin = new int[3];
    public int[] Origin {
        get {  return origin;} 
        set{
            if (value.Length >3) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            else origin = value;
        }
    }
```

> Don't expose the field. Make it as property. Validate the value in property setter. –  Sriram Sakthivel

This worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should encapsulate the array in a class, instantiating it from the constructor. Use a public getter and private setter to control access:

```
public int[] MyArray {
    get;
    private set;
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZsjrsN